# Iterating and selecting a specific array from a multidimensional array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

Imagine I have something like this:

```
 import numpy as np
 arra = np.arange(16).reshape(2, 2, 4)
```

which gives

```
 array([[[0, 1, 2, 3],  
      [4, 5, 6, 7]],  
      [[8, 9, 10, 11],  
      [12, 13, 14, 15]]])
```

and I want to make a loop that runs along specific subarrays (in this case, I want to run along each 'column' of each 'matrix') and sum the result (that is, selecting 0 and 4 and summing them (4), selecting 1 and 5 and summing them (6), ..., selecting 3 and 7 and summing them (10), selecting 8 and 12 and summing them (20), ..., selecting 11 and 15 and summing them (26)).

I had thought doing that with the apparently natural:

```
 for i in arra[i, j, k]:  
     for j in arra[i, j, k]:  
         for k in arra[i, j, k]:  
             sum...
```

The problem is that Python certainly doesn't allow to do what I want in this way. If it were a 2D array it would be easier as I know that the iterator first runs through the rows, so you can transpose to run along the columns, but for a multidimensional (3D in this case) array (N, M, P) with N, M, P >> 1, I was wondering how it could be done.

**EDIT:** This question has a continuation here: [Choosing and iterating specific sub-arrays in multidimensional arrays in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35775040/choosing-and-iterating-specific-sub-arrays-in-multidimensional-arrays-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) to get this done:

```
import numpy as np
arra = np.arange(16).reshape(2, 2, 4)
```

Then the command:

```
map(sum, arra)
```

gives you the desired output:

```
[array([ 4,  6,  8, 10]), array([20, 22, 24, 26])]
```

Alternatively, you can also use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
res = [sum(ai) for ai in arra]
```

Then `res` looks like this:

```
[array([ 4,  6,  8, 10]), array([20, 22, 24, 26])]
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to add identical rows - as you mentioned in the comments below this answer - you can do (using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)):

```
map(sum, zip(*arra))
```

which gives you the desired output:

```
[array([ 8, 10, 12, 14]), array([16, 18, 20, 22])]
```

For the sake of completeness also the list comprehension:

```
[sum(ai) for ai in zip(*arra)]
```

which gives you the same output.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is very useful, but I was wondering..., imagine you are interested, in the same example as before, in summing the values of the even rows, that is, 0 + 8, 1 + 9, 2 + 10, ..., 4 + 12, 7 + 15 (summing by columns but in even rows). Is there a general way to do it?

Comment: @David: Sure. I edited my answer and added the solution for that as well.

Comment: Thank you but I was still wondering if there are more generic ways. Imagine I want to add the first with the last, and the intermediate, that is, 0 + 12, 1 + 13, ..., 4 + 8, 5 + 9, ... 7 + 11. Is it still possible? Would you need a clever transposing of the axes?

Comment: Then you might want to open a new question and use this question here as reference; it does not make that much sense to discuss all kind of special cases in the comments.