# Choosing and iterating specific sub-arrays in multidimensional arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

This is a question that comes from the post here [Iterating and selecting a specific array from a multidimensional array in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35769536/iterating-and-selecting-a-specific-array-from-a-multidimensional-array-in-python)

In that post, user @Cleb solved what it was my original problem: how to perform a sum through columns in a 3d array:

```
 import numpy as np
 arra = np.arange(16).reshape(2, 2, 4)
```

which gives

```
 array([[[0, 1, 2, 3],  
     [4, 5, 6, 7]],  
     [[8, 9, 10, 11],  
     [12, 13, 14, 15]]])
```

and the problem was how to perform the sum of columns in each matrix, i. e., 0 + 4, 1 + 5, ... , 8 + 12, ..., 11 + 15. It was solved by @Cleb.

Then I wondered how to do it in the case of a sum of 0 + 8, 1 + 9, ..., 4 + 12, ..., 7 + 15, (odd and even columns) which was also solved by @Cleb.

But then I wondered if there are a general idea (which can be modified in each specific case). Imagine you can add the first and the last rows and the center rows, in columns, separately, i. e., 0 + 12, 1 + 13, ..., 3 + 15, 4 + 8, 5 + 9, ..., 7 + 11.

Is there a general way? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the how exactly `arra` is defined, you can shift your values appropriately using [`np.roll`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html):

```
arra_mod = np.roll(arra, arra.shape[2])
```

`arra_mod` then looks as follows:

```
array([[[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [ 0,  1,  2,  3]],

       [[ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]]])
```

Now you can simply use the command from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35769536/iterating-and-selecting-a-specific-array-from-a-multidimensional-array-in-python?lq=1) to get your desired output:

```
map(sum, arra_mod)
```

which gives you the desired output:

```
[array([12, 14, 16, 18]), array([12, 14, 16, 18])]
```

You can also use a list comprehension

```
[sum(ai) for ai in arra_mod]
```

which gives you the same output.

If you prefer one-liner, you can therefore simply do:

```
map(sum, np.roll(arra, arra.shape[2]))
```